# Why am I getting an "uninitialized variable" error

Tags: regex, perl, split

Just wanted to know what I was possibly doing wrong with my code to get an error. I keep getting 
the error code is:

"use of uninitialized value $value in hash element at C:\begperl/final.pl line 136,138,167,169,  line 2006 (#1)"

I go to print out my arrays and they all print though so I am at a bit of a loss as to why my variable is empty. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

#opens txt file: read mode
open MYFILE, '<', 'source_file.txt' or die $!;

#opens output txt file: write mode
open OUT, '>', 'Summary_Report.txt' or die $!;

my @header;

my $i = 0;
my $packet_size = 0;

my $start_time = undef;
my $end_time;

my @source_ip;
my @source_port;
my $src_port;
my @src_port;

my @dest_ip;
my @dest_port;
my $destination_port;
my @destination_port;

while (<MYFILE>) { 
    chomp; #break new line

    #separate pieces of information from TCPDUMP into list
    @header = split (/\s+/, $_);

    if (/^\d+:\d+/) {

##############################T I M E###################################

    #defining first 'line & time' as 'special'
    if (/^22:28/ && !defined($start_time)) {
        $start_time = $header[0];
        #print "$start_time\n"; check
    }   

    if (/22:28/) {
        $end_time = $header[0];
    }       

############################S O U R C E##################################

    #categorizing each section of ip's from source
    @source_ip = split ('\.', $header[2]);

    #joining ip's together
    $source_ip[$i] = join '.', @source_ip[0 .. 3];
    #print $source_ip[$i]; 

    @source_port = split (':', $source_ip[4]);
    $src_port[$i] = $source_port[0];

#########################D E S T I N A T I O N###########################

    #categorizing each section of ip's from destination
    @dest_ip = split ('\.', $header[4]);

    #joining ip's together
    $dest_ip[$i] = join '.', @dest_ip[0 .. 3];
    #print $dest_ip[$i]; 

    @dest_port = split (':', $dest_ip[4]);
    $destination_port[$i] = $dest_port[0];
    #print $destination_port[$i];

#############################L E N G T H#################################

    #-1 represents length
    #transferring $header[-1] into 'total length'
    $packet_size += $header[-1];
    #print $packet_size; 

    $i++;

    }
}

my @total_timesplit;

my @s_timesplit = split (':', $start_time);
#print @s_timesplit;

my @e_timesplit = split (':', $end_time);
#print @e_timesplit; 

for $i (0 .. 2) {
    $total_timesplit[$i] = $e_timesplit[$i] - $s_timesplit[$i];
    #print @total_timesplit;
}

#Yields average packet size
my $avg_length = $packet_size/$i;
#print $avg_length;

close MYFILE;

#########################D A T A S E C T I O N###########################

open MYFILE, '<', 'source_file.txt' or die $!;

my $user = 0;
my $pass = 0;

#separating loop to reset values#
while (<MYFILE>) { 

    #finds all instances of USER
    $user++ if /USER/i;
    #print $user;

    #finds all instances of PASS
    $pass++ if /PASS/i;
    #print $pass;

}

##############################SOURCEIPHASH##############################

my %seenip_source;
my @uniqueip_source;
my $sourceips_unique;

foreach my $value (@source_ip) {
    if (! $seenip_source{$value}) {
        push @uniqueip_source, $value;
        $seenip_source{$value} = 1;

    }
}
$sourceips_unique = @uniqueip_source;


#########################SOURCEPORTHASH#################################

my %seenport_source;
my @uniqueport_source;
my $sourceports_unique;

foreach my $value (@source_port) {
    if (! $seenport_source{$value}) {
        push @uniqueport_source, $value;
        $seenport_source{$value} = 1;
    }
}
$sourceports_unique = @uniqueport_source;

##########################DESTINATIONIPHASH#############################

my %seenip_dest;
my @uniqueip_dest;
my $destips_unique;

foreach my $value (@dest_ip) {
    if (! $seenip_dest{$value}) {
        push @uniqueip_dest, $value;
        $seenip_dest{$value} = 1;
    }
}
$destips_unique = @uniqueip_dest;

#########################DESTINATIONPORTSHASH###########################

my %seenport_dest;
my @uniqueport_dest;
my $destports_unique;

foreach my $value (@dest_port) {
    if (! $seenport_dest{$value}) {
        push @uniqueport_dest, $value;
        $seenport_dest{$value} = 1;
    }
}
$destports_unique = @uniqueport_dest;

#########################################################################
```

Comment: Please only post the **relevant** parts of your code.

Comment: Please (a) include the exact error message, with line number; (b) include the sample data; (c) investigate how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so that there is as little extraneous code to be studied as possible.  It is most important, though, that the code, data and error messages be synchronized.

Comment: just posted it. And I was told by other members to copy and paste my whole code into this and now your telling me not to. I can't win.

Comment: You've used `$value` at least 4 times for different purposes (ports, IP addresses, once unsed too).  The line number should tell you which version of `$value` the runtime is claiming is uninitialized.  My bet is one of the arrays you're iterating over has an undefined value in it.  But that's a guess.

Comment: If other members told you to jump off a cliff, would you? Post as little code as possible that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
my $i = 0;
while (<MYFILE>)
    @source_ip = split ('\.', $header[2]);
    $source_ip[$i] = join '.', @source_ip[0 .. 3];
    ...
    $i++;
}
```

The `split` line probably creates four elements, so `source_ip`  is something like `("111", "112", "113", "114")`. You join these four fields together and write them into the $`i`-th field. For `$i == 0`, this overwrites the first field:

```
("111.112.113.114", "112", "113", "114")
```

For `$i == 4`, this appends a field:

```
("111", "112", "113", "114", "111.112.113.114")
```

And for `$i == 5` or larger, there will be an empty field in between:

```
("111", "112", "113", "114", undef, "111.112.113.114")
```

Later, you loop through that array:

```
foreach my $value (@source_ip) {
    if (! $seenip_source{$value}) {
...
```

so at one point `$value` is `undef`. A *hash* can only use strings as keys, so the `undef` is coerced to the empty string `''`, and a warning is emitted.

How can this be corrected? I am not sure, because I'm not sure about the intent of your code (I have no idea how your input data will look, and what output you desire). Generally, you will want to declare variables as close to their use as possible, and not overwrite them. I can imagine that you actually intended:

```
my @source_ip;
while (<MYFILE>)
    my @ip_parts = split ('\.', $header[2]);
    push @source_ip, join '.', @ip_parts[0 .. 3];
    ...
}
```

The [`push` builtin](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) appends elements to the end of a given array, so you don't need to specify an index. Using different variables for the temporary `@ip_parts` and the array you store the results in makes it easier to avoid errors – variables are cheap, so there is no need to use them sparingly!